# Question about derivative of transformation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, differentiation, rotational-kinematics

I have a question that result equation is how it has derived.

When we have a following equation,

$$\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\delta r}{\delta t}+\omega \times r.$$
$\omega$ is angular velocity, $r$ is position vector.

It expresses that how movement of vector $r$ which belong to B coordinate is looks to view of A coordinate.

But, If do derivative one time more,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}
=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\frac{\delta r}{\delta t}+\omega \times r\right)$$

Result in the Book is as follows.

$$\frac{\delta ^2r}{\delta ^2t}+\frac{\delta \omega }{\delta t}\times r+2\omega \times \frac{\delta r}{\delta t}+\omega \times \left(\omega \times r\right)$$

I really can not find a any clue for it....

Could  you help me? Please let me know...

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your "$\delta$" symbol means versus your "$d$" symbol. But, regardless, if you allow them to commute and literally just plug and chug the algebra you will arrive at the book answer.

Comment: vector "r" is fixed in coordinate A. and it is rotating. But, when coordinate B are watching vector "r", it will be looks "r" is rotating and coordinate A also rotating, because "r" is fixed in coordinate A. so, "δ" is meaing that it is derivation belong to coordinate A.

Answer (score 0):

Given a fixed frame $A$ with fixed basis $\hat e_i$ and a rotating frame $\tilde A$ with rotating basis $\hat {\tilde e}_i$, we have, by definition of the components of $\vec r$ in each basis:
$$
\vec r \equiv \sum_i x_i \hat e_i \equiv \sum_i \tilde x_i \hat {\tilde e}_i
$$

By definition:
$$
\frac{\delta \vec r}{\delta t}\equiv \sum_i\frac{d\tilde x_i}{dt}\hat {\tilde e}_i
$$

We also have:
$$
\frac{d\hat{\tilde e}_i}{dt} = \vec \omega \times \hat {\tilde e}_i 
$$

Combining the above three equations leads to the relationship we already know:
$$
\frac{d\vec r}{dt}=\frac{\delta \vec r}{\delta t} + \vec \omega \times \vec r
$$

The above comes from differentiating
$$
\vec r = \sum_i \tilde x_i \hat {\tilde e}_i\qquad (1)
$$
wrt time.

We can also differentiate Eq (1) with respect to time *twice*:
$$
\frac{d^2 \vec r}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\sum_i \left(\frac{d\tilde x_i}{dt}\hat{\tilde e}_i + \tilde x_i\vec\omega\times\hat {\tilde e}_i \right)
$$
$$
=\sum_i\left(\frac{d^2 \tilde x_i}{dt^2}\hat{\tilde e}_i
+\frac{d\tilde x_i}{dt}\vec \omega\times\hat{\tilde e}_i
+\frac{d \tilde x_i}{dt}\vec\omega\times\hat {\tilde e}_i
+\tilde x_i\vec\omega\times\vec \omega\times\hat{\tilde e}_i
\right)
$$

By definition:
$$
\frac{\delta^2r}{\delta t^2}
=\sum_i\frac{d^2 \tilde x_i}{dt^2}\hat{\tilde e}_i\;,
$$
which shows that
$$
\frac{d^2 \vec r}{dt^2} 
=\frac{\delta^2r}{\delta t^2}
+\vec \omega\times\frac{\delta \vec r}{\delta t}
+\vec\omega\times\frac{\delta \vec r}{\delta t}
+\vec\omega\times\vec \omega\times\vec r
$$

Comment: I really appreciate you hft ! feels I reached to answer almost !!

Comment: If you do not mind, May I could ask one more question to you ? Thanks. In the equation, X is meaning of cross product. it would be fit with cross product as well ?

Comment: ddt δrδt -> δδt drdt, May I could ask you where could find a reference for it sir ?

Comment: I can't tell what you are writing, you need to use MathJax notation.

Comment: Just go back to the definitions and do everything explicitly in the rotating basis. I updated the answer, but I will not say anymore because this is too close to doing your homework for you.

Comment: I appreciate for your help, hft ! I am doing it for my personal hobby in control theory area.

Comment: I do not have any idea how to say thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer to hft's, consider:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2} &= \frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{\delta\mathbf{r}}{\delta t} + \boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{r}\big)\\[5pt]
&= \frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{\delta\mathbf{r}}{\delta t} \big)+ \frac{d\boldsymbol{\omega}}{dt}\times\mathbf{r}+ \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{\delta^2\mathbf{r}}{\delta t^2} + \boldsymbol{\omega}\times\frac{\delta\mathbf{r}}{\delta t} + \frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\delta t}\times \mathbf{r} + \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \frac{\delta\mathbf{r}}{\delta t} +\boldsymbol{\omega}\times \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \mathbf{r}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{\delta^2\mathbf{r}}{\delta t^2} + \frac{\delta\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\delta t}\times \mathbf{r} + 2 \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \frac{\delta\mathbf{r}}{\delta t}  + \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \mathbf{r}.
\end{align}

Comment: I appreciate deeply, Sahand Tabatabaei !. But, I really want to know that "ω×δrδt+ω×ω×r" is where from.. (in the second from last). May I could ask more ?